# Handling Informative Censored Data in Comparative Analysis of Cumulative Outcomes Across Groups

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, group-differences, hazard, kaplan-meier

Hello Cross Validated community,

I am working on a dataset that involves multiple groups undergoing a series of interventions, with the aim to achieve a binary outcome (e.g., success or failure). The participants in each group can undergo multiple interventions until a specific condition is met (e.g., success achieved, all options exhausted, or opting out). The dataset is structured with variables: number of interventions per participant ($num.intervention_i$), binary outcome ($BinaryOutcome_i$), and number of completed interventions ($num.completed_i$). The groups are expected to have different probabilities of success, partly due to varying intervention capacities (e.g., different average numbers of possible interventions).

I'm interested in comparing the overall probability of success (considering all interventions) and the per-intervention probability of success across these groups. However, I face challenges due to censored data - participants who opt out before exhausting all intervention options. This censoring is non-random as it's influenced by the remaining number of possible interventions.

My questions are:

What statistical methods can I use to compare the overall and per-intervention probabilities of success across groups, considering the censored nature of the data?

Given that censored participants could have varying numbers of remaining interventions, how should this factor be incorporated into the analysis?  Would logistic regression model which includes numbers of remaining potential interventions as confounder be suitable?

I initially considered using survival analysis techniques like Kaplan-Meier or Cumulative Hazard Function. However, I'm concerned these might be inappropriate due to the informative nature of the censoring.

How can I approach the comparison of per-intervention success rates, especially in light of the censored data?

I'm seeking advice on the best analytical strategies to address these challenges, ensuring that my comparisons are valid and account for the complexities of the dataset.

Thank you for your insights and suggestions.